# Non-dynamic approach to do a series of union statements on table value function tvf

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table valued function that returns some details about a specific account.  Something like this.  Far more complex but you get the idea.  It's a multi line TVF if that makes a difference (not an inline statement)

```
select * from dbo.TBFDetailsByAccountKey(1234)

-----------------------------------------------
date       |    amount    |     detail        |
-----------------------------------------------
4/1/2012   |    10.23     |  payment stuff    |
4/2/2012   |    12.40     |  other stuff      |
4/2/2012   |    14.23     |  second pmt today |
```

I now have need to call this same TVF repeatedly in a series of UNION ALL statements in order to return the details for all the account key's contained within a set of deposits.  Is there a way to do this without resorting to dynamic sql?

My current approach is this... but it uses dynamic sql and I keep thinking there should be a better "non dynamic" way.

```
DECLARE @pResult varchar(max)

SELECT @pResult = COALESCE(@pResult + ' UNION ALL ', '') + 
        'SELECT * FROM dbo.TBFDetailsByAccountKey(' + 
        Cast(AccountKey AS VarChar(25)) + ')'
    FROM Account WHERE DepositKey = @pDepositKey

EXEC(@pResult)  /* execute dynamic sql created above */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems [CROSS APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) was designed to do this exact job:

```
SELECT AccountDetails.*
FROM Account
CROSS APPLY
(
  select * 
    from dbo.TBFDetailsByAccountKey(Account.AccountKey)
) AccountDetails
WHERE Account.DepositKey = @pDepositKey
```